# Can't implement OAuth in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, oauth

I'm playing around with App Development by means of playing around with PhoneGap (HTML, CSS, JavaScript). I'm stuck trying to implement Instagram authentication via OAuth.io. Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>X</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone" class="pagewrapper">
    <div data-role="panel" id="rightpanel" data-position="right">

        <p>hej</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="leftpanel" data-position="left">

        <p>hej</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role='header' id="header" data-id='pheader' data-position='fixed' data-transition='none'>
            <span id="right-menu-toggle"><a href="#rightpanel"><img src="img/menu-toggle.png" width="25px" height="25px"/></a></span>
            <span id="left-menu-toggle"><a href="#leftpanel"><img src="img/settings-toggle.png" width="25px" height="25px"/></a></span>
    </div>


    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <button type="bytton" onclick="oAuthfct()">Instagram!</button>
        <p id="test">hej</p>
    </div>




</div>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/com.oauthio.plugins.oauthio/www/oauth.js"></script> 
<script src="lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function oAuthfct() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";
    OAuth.initialize('utBjpWgXLntpPoz3t2Tg_9pzOLB');
    OAuth.popup('instagram', function(error, success){
  // See the result below
});
}
```

The Paragraph is changing, so I'm sure that my JavaScript file is loaded. But nothing else happens. I'm testing it in the PhoneGap Developer emulator.

I've tried testing it in Firefox as well, where I get the following errors:

> ReferenceError: module is not defined module.exports = { oauth.js
>   (line 76, col 1)
>
> ReferenceError: OAuth is not defined
>   OAuth.initialize('utIjrESXUntpPfz5t2tg_3pzODM'); app.js (line 26, col
>   2)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add 'OAuth' as dependency in your app module?

```
.controller('LoginController', ['OAuth',function(OAuth)
...
]
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and haven't heard about dependencies before like this before. Can you elaborate a bit please?